# Nautilus Icon not showing window indicators

Tags: 16.04, unity, nautilus

Running Ubuntu 16.04, upgraded from 15.10.

I installed Dolphin alongside the existing Nautilus for testing purposes. Ever since, Nautilus is no longer showing open windows in the sidebar. The *Files* icon looks as if no window was opened and clicking it opens a new one. Typically it should show indicators for the number of open windows (up to three). Same problem for when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, the window icon is simply not there. Minimizing a Nautilus window therefore means that I lose it.

How can this be fixed?

[image]
*Nautilus icon now indicating the open window*

I tried removing the icon from the unity sidebar, but then no icon appears when I open *Files* in the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem did not start with dolphin. It seems like a unity bug.
As a workaround (I'm still trying to figure out a better solution) in the terminal, type:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz   
setsid unity
```

This got my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> working, and restored my tab on the side. <strike>but needs to be done on every launch.</strike>

I originally followed the [instructions here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-reset-unity-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal):

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

But when I just ran `setsid unity` after removing dolphin (no `compiz` reload), the default behavior was restored.

Comment: "Unfortunately" I can't check your solution because the problem as resolved itself on my machine. I assumed it was patched.