# nautilus windows don't show up in Launcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, window

For some time now when I open a Nautilus window, no icon appears in the Launcher, and when <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>ing, the Nautilus windows are ignored too.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with unity.

**EDIT:** I'm no longer experiencing this problem. It went away roughly at the time I uninstalled Dolphin, may that's what was causing it.

Comment: Same problem as here maybe?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/764764/nautilus-icon-not-showing-window-indicators

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in 16.04 see [#1578792](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1578792) and [1572348](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1572348)

As a workaround till this issue is fixed you need to pin Nautilus to the Launcher.

1. Open Dash and search for nautilus
2. Drag and Drop Nautilus icon to the Launcher

Make sure you leave the nautilus icon on the Launcher (no pressing Unlock from Launcher) as otherwise the icon will disappear again.

Comment: This only makes a shortcut in the launcher, but doesn't persist the currently opened one. In effect, a new window would always be opened when navigating back to nautilus.